# Cannot play sound file on multiple platforms in Qt 5.7.0

Tags: qt, audio, ogg, qtmultimedia

With Qt 5.7.0, I was playing a sound in a qml by including an Audio object like this:

```
Audio {
  id: music
  source: "sound/testmusic.mp3"
  autoLoad: true
  autoPlay: true
}
```

It played in windows, but not in linux. Why not?

Error message that came up in linux:

> Cannot connect to server socket err = Filen eller katalogen finns inte
>   Cannot connect to server request channel jack server is not running or
>   cannot be started JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not
>   done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
>   JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for
>   4294967295, skipping unlock

"Filen eller katalogen finns inte" is in swedish and should be translated to "Missing file or directory".

We converted the sound file to ogg and changed the qml to:

```
Audio {
  id: music
  source: "sound/testmusic.ogg"
  autoLoad: true
  autoPlay: true
}
```

Now it plays on linux but not in windows.

Why not?

I install the following in windows to see what could be done:

- http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/oggdsf/opencodecs_0.85.17777.exe
- https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.9.1/gstreamer-1.0-x86-1.9.1.msi
- https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.9.1/gstreamer-1.0-x86_64-1.9.1.msi

I deleted the build directory and ran the project in windows. Silent.

What needs to be done?

Comment: For Ubuntu 12.04, I had to install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg to get mp3s to play. To get mp3s to work on Ubuntu 16.04, I had to install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg and gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly manually from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly (and its dependencies).